# Hit count for kubernetes services object

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am writing a custom Kubernetes controller and resource to keep track of the number of times a service object is called. The idea behind this is to add a "hitcount" field to the resource and update it every time a service is invoked. (Meaning update the count every time a request is made to the pod that is part of the service)

Is this possible? Does the kubernetes API have an option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you're in fact trying to implement a metric inside kubernetes api. It's hardly a controller though. In a nutshell, controller is piece of software that continuously realizes an intent stated in kubernetes API in a real world.

Semantics aside, status object in kubernetes API is defined in it's type. For Pod, at the moment of writing of this answer it's [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go#L2978) and it's not an extensible one. So you can't really put your metric into the Pod object.

The question that this naturally poses is why not use something that is expected for metrics collection and visualization like prometheus/grafana ?

All of that aside, you also have an issue of how will you expose/collect that metric. Istio could help here, or the software in pod it self could expose it's metrics (which, if possible, is the best route to take imo)

Comment: I agree. This seems more like a prometheus integration. My initial goal was to capture the hit count, last access time, and other metadata, and have the UpdateFunc (for the informer) method kick in, after a resync period. Based on the data gathered, the controller would automate other things. But looks like this just not possible with the core API.